# How to use UILabel and DateFormatter to display the current time?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the UILabel and DateFormatter to display the time (date, min, sec) whenever a user launches the APP.

I currently found this from stackoverflow

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

but it seems that I have to pass in a time into the formatter. How do I just get the UILabel to display the current time instead of a fixed time?

Comment: You can use a repeating timer

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to show a digital clock where the time updates each second or something else?

Comment: @rmaddy, no I am just trying to display the time when the user launches the APP.

Comment: OK, then what issue are you having? BTW - don't set a hardcoded format when display a date and time to the user. Use the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties so the date is shown in a properly localized format.

Comment: Are you hiding the status bar? Because the status bar already displays the current time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the current time without passing any variables, You do so by:

```
let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

let exactlyCurrentTime: Date = Date()
print(dateFormatterPrint.stringFromDate(exactlyCurrentTime))

// e.g Set your label text:
myLabel.text = "Current Time: \(dateFormatterPrint.stringFromDate(exactlyCurrentTime))"
```

For example, If we want: `Friday, Nov 16, 2018`  | We set: `EEEE, MMM d, yyyy`

I do also recommend a visit of [NSDateFormatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com) to understand how `dateFormat` works.

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

```
label.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```